# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field with datetime field in django modelform

Tags: django

I'm using django 1.8. When I use a datetime field, I get an error saying that the field is unknown.
I checked many times that the name is spelled right.
Any ideas what's going on here?

```
class MyTable(models.Model):
    origin = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class MyTableForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyTable
        fields = ['origin', 'last_modified']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 19, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 22, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 74, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/user/src/biosys/myapp/myapp/admin.py", line 6, in <module>
    from forms import *
  File "/home/user/src/biosys/myapp/myapp/forms.py", line 46, in <module>
    class InterpForm(ModelForm):
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 295, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (last_modified) specified for MyTable
```

Comment: Have you made and run migrations?

Comment: Yes. I can query and get the last_modified dates.